# High windowserver memory usage (6GB+) on MacOS

Tags: macos, memory, apple-silicon

I've got the 16GB M1 MacBook Pro and windowserver is using huge ammounts of RAM, meaning that my swap is over 3GB. **Is this normal behaviour?**

I don't have any external displays connected and it's pretty annoying when trying to run an Android emulator.

[image: Activity Monitor]

Comment: I'd be bothered by how much RAM Firefox is using - bearing in mind that doesn't include any open tabs, that's just the app itself. Safari here with 30 or more tabs is only eating 300MB. & appleeventsd at 4GB, mine is 7MB. Even mds is running high.

Comment: The linked question is concerned with CPU rather than RAM, though there's a possibility they may be linked.

Comment: this eclecticlight article was informative for me, remember that M1 machines don't have separate graphics memory like Intel machines, it's all shared, and windowserver memory usage can go higher when connecting external monitors:  https://eclecticlight.co/2022/02/22/windowserver-is-hungry-for-memory-on-m1-macs/

Comment: @TomJNowell - you should probably add that as an answer - would make it more searchable for future users.

Comment: honestly I'm not sure what the question is, it's phrased as a statement, is Charlie asking why it's taking up memory, or is Charlie asking how to reduce its footprint? Prevention steps? I don't feel I could write an answer, or that a hyperlink answer would be appropriate, it's fine as a comment though :)